# VS2012 D3D Debugging - Viewing all shader output

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, direct3d, direct3d11

So previously I have always used PIX for debugging, but since I now have access to VS2012 I figured I would give that a try to debug some draw call that is causing problems.

I have been able to get the event list for a frame fine, and for my draw call I can see the pipeline for the input assembler, vertex shader, pixel shader and output merger, and I can see my problem appears to by with some vertex shader output / pixel shader input texture coordinates.

However VS2012 just seems to want to give me some PNG visualising the vertex positions, which are not the problem... [MSDN Graphics Pipeline Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh873194.aspx) seems to just tell me how to do that as well.

What I really want is a table that shows my vertex shader input vertices (so each column being a vertex element, and a row per vertex), and what the outputs are for each of those vertices (so some more columns or adjacent table).

In PIX there was the "PreVS" and "PostVS" tabs on a mesh view, surely VS2012 has this somewhere and isn't limited to viewing positions?

Answer (score 0):

VSGD ( for Visual Studio Graphic Diagnostic ) is "hélas" far from the deprecated PiX in terms of functionality and worse than PiX in terms of bugs. I recommend you to use NSIGHT 3.1 from nvidia or GPUPerfStudio from ATI ( depends of your GPU ) if you need a tool useful for debugging a real 3D frame.